# changes url of setup.exe (deploy ClickOnce) using Msbuild

Tags: deployment, msbuild, clickonce, installation, bootstrapper

I use msbuild for using setup -url="location"...

I publish application using ClickOnce and I want changes the url in the setup.exe.

```
<Exec Command="$(PublishDir)\setup -url=$(ProviderUrl)" />
```

Another problem is that after using the /url switch to change out the URL, it appears message for manually confirming that the signature will be invalided for the assembly.

two issues:

1. how can use setup -url=http://.... in mode silent ?? I dont want that appears the message for confirming.
2. How can signature the setup.exe again ??

any solution about it ?? Thanks mister

My msbuild

```
<Target Name="PublishClickOnce">

<Exec Command="$(PublishDir)\setup -url=$(ProviderUrl)" /> 

<Exec Command="$(Mage) -u $(PublishDir)\Frk.Security.CarWin.application -pu $(ProviderUrl)" /> 

<Exec Command="$(Mage) -u $(PublishDir)\Frk.Security.CarWin.application -cf $(CertDir)\Frk.Security.CarWin_TemporaryKey.pfx" /> 

 </Target>
```

Any help, please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of your question from yesterday?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185201

Answer (score 2):

This how  we build ClickOnce applications with TeamBuild for multiple environments

You can read my original blogpost [here](http://hakanforss.wordpress.com/2009/04/25/how-to-build-clickonce-applications-with-teambuild-for-multiple-environments/)

This is how you call the ClickOnce build from you TeamBuild project file (line breaks added for readability):

```
<Msbuild
      Projects="$(SolutionRoot)\ConfigFiles\BuildClickOnce.targets"
      Targets="BuildClickOnce"
      Properties="SourceDir=$(SourceDir);PublishDir=$(PublishDir);                      ClickOnceAppName=$(ClickOnceAppName);ClickOnceExeFile=$(ClickOnceExeFile);                      ClickOnceProduct=$(ClickOnceProduct);Company=$(Company);                      ClickOnceDescription=$(ClickOnceDescription);ClickOnceUrl=$(ClickOnceUrl);                      VersionNumber=$(VersionNumber);SigningCert=$(SigningCert);                      SigningCertPassword=$(SigningCertPassword)"
        />
```

For every environment or configuration change you want you use this. Below you find the BuildClickOnce.targets file (line breaks added for readability):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets" />
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets"/>
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\SDC\Microsoft.Sdc.Common.tasks"/>


    <Target Name="BuildClickOnce" DependsOnTargets="">

        <PropertyGroup>      
            <ClickOnceApplicationUrl>$(ClickOnceUrl)$(ClickOnceAppName).application</ClickOnceApplicationUrl>
            <AppPublishDir>$(PublishDir)</AppPublishDir>
            <SdkPath>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A</SdkPath>
        </PropertyGroup>

        <BuildStep
          TeamFoundationServerUrl="$(TeamFoundationServerUrl)"
          BuildUri="$(BuildUri)"
          Message="Buildning $(ClickOnceAppName) ClickOnce version: $(VersionNumber)">
            <Output TaskParameter="Id" PropertyName="StepId" />
        </BuildStep>


    <CallTarget Targets="UpdateWebPage" />

        <!--
  ************************************************
  Generate application manifest
  ************************************************
  -->
        <Exec
        Command="mage.exe -New Application -TrustLevel FullTrust                  -ToFile &quot;$(AppPublishDir)\$(ClickOnceExeFile).manifest&quot;                  -Name &quot;$(ClickOnceAppName)&quot; -Version &quot;$(VersionNumber)&quot;                 -FromDirectory &quot;$(AppPublishDir)&quot;"
        WorkingDirectory="$(SdkPath)\Bin"/>

        <!--
  ************************************************
  Signing application manifest
  ************************************************
  -->
        <Exec Condition="'$(SigningCertPassword)'==''"
          Command="mage.exe -Sign &quot;$(AppPublishDir)\$(ClickOnceExeFile).manifest&quot;                    -CertFile &quot;$(SigningCert)&quot;"
          WorkingDirectory="$(SdkPath)\Bin"  />

        <Exec Condition="'$(SigningCertPassword)'!=''"
            Command="mage.exe -Sign &quot;$(AppPublishDir)\$(ClickOnceExeFile).manifest&quot;                      -CertFile &quot;$(SigningCert)&quot; -Password &quot;$(SigningCertPassword)&quot;"
            WorkingDirectory="$(SdkPath)\Bin"/>

        <!--
  ************************************************
  Renaming source files to .deploy
  ************************************************
  -->
        <ItemGroup>
            <SourceFilesToRename Include="$(AppPublishDir)\**\*.*"                  Exclude="$(AppPublishDir)\*.manifest;$(AppPublishDir)\*.htm"/>
            <SourceFilesToDelete Include="$(AppPublishDir)\**\*.*"                  Exclude="$(AppPublishDir)\*.application;$(AppPublishDir)\*.manifest;$(AppPublishDir)\*.htm"/>
        </ItemGroup>

        <Copy
            SourceFiles="@(SourceFilesToRename)"
            DestinationFiles="@(SourceFilesToRename->'$(AppPublishDir)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension).deploy')"
        />

        <Delete Files="@(SourceFilesToDelete)"/>


        <!--
  ************************************************
  Generating deployment manifest
  ************************************************
  -->

        <GenerateDeploymentManifest
          MapFileExtensions="true"
          AssemblyName="$(ClickOnceAppName).application"
          AssemblyVersion="$(VersionNumber)"
          MinimumRequiredVersion="$(VersionNumber)"
          DeploymentUrl="$(ClickOnceApplicationUrl)"
          Description="$(ClickOnceDescription)"
          Product="$(ClickOnceProduct)"
          Publisher="$(Company)"
          SupportUrl="$(SupportUrl)"
          EntryPoint="$(AppPublishDir)\$(ClickOnceExeFile).manifest"
          Install="true"
          UpdateEnabled="true"
          UpdateMode="Foreground"
          OutputManifest="$(PublishDir)\$(ClickOnceAppName).application"/>

        <!--
  ************************************************
  Signing application manifest
  ************************************************
  -->
        <Exec Condition="'$(SigningCertPassword)'==''"
            Command="mage.exe -Sign &quot;$(PublishDir)\$(ClickOnceAppName).application&quot;                     -CertFile &quot;$(SigningCert)&quot;"
            WorkingDirectory="$(SdkPath)\bin"/>
        <Exec Condition="'$(SigningCertPassword)'!=''"
            Command="mage.exe -Sign &quot;$(PublishDir)\$(ClickOnceAppName).application&quot;                     -CertFile &quot;$(SigningCert)&quot; -Password &quot;$(SigningCertPassword)&quot;"
            WorkingDirectory="$(SdkPath)\bin"/>


        <!--
  ************************************************
  Generating Bootstrapper
  ************************************************
  -->
        <ItemGroup>
            <BootstrapperFile Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.2.0">
                <ProductName>Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0</ProductName>
            </BootstrapperFile>
        </ItemGroup>


        <GenerateBootstrapper
          ApplicationFile="$(ClickOnceAppName).application"
          ApplicationName="$(ClickOnceAppName)"
          ApplicationUrl="$(ClickOnceUrl)"
          BootstrapperItems="@(BootstrapperFile)"
          Culture="en"
          FallbackCulture="en-US"
          CopyComponents="true"
          Validate="false"
          Path="$(SdkPath)\Bootstrapper"
          OutputPath="$(PublishDir)"/>


        <BuildStep
          TeamFoundationServerUrl="$(TeamFoundationServerUrl)"
          BuildUri="$(BuildUri)"
          Id="$(StepId)"
          Status="Succeeded"/>

        <OnError ExecuteTargets="MarkBuildStepAsFailed" />
    </Target>

    <!--
  ************************************************
  Marks a buildstep as failed
  ************************************************
  -->
    <Target Name="MarkBuildStepAsFailed">
        <BuildStep
          TeamFoundationServerUrl="$(TeamFoundationServerUrl)"
          BuildUri="$(BuildUri)"
          Id="$(StepId)"
          Status="Failed"/>
    </Target>

    <!--
  ************************************************
  Updating web page
  ************************************************
  -->
    <Target Name="UpdateWebPage">
        <ItemGroup>
            <WebPage Include="$(PublishDir)\publish.htm" />
        </ItemGroup>

        <RegEx
          Condition="Exists(@(WebPage))"
          Path="@(WebPage)"
          RegularExpression="#VERSION#"
          NewValue="$(VersionNumber)"
          Force="true"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the url you're better off doing:

1. Edit the .application and replace the url in the deploymentProvider
2. Use [GenerateBootstrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164294.aspx) from  to build a new setup.exe
3. Sign application and setup

I found using the -url parameter made the setup invalid after I signed it